# How to pass a list to .agg in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have to do this command:

```
df.groupBy('docid', 'vehicle_vin').pivot('intervaltype').agg(first('NAME_COLUMN1').alias('NAME_COLUMN1'))
```

And i want to pass dynamically the name of the column that are saved in a list:

```
(NAME_COLUMN1,NAME_COLUMN2,NAME_COLUMN3.....)
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Where do you want to pass the list of fields?

Comment: this looks like Python not Scala?